# The module `./index` could not be found from Indeed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I've created a new project using react-native init 'project name' and everything is good, once I run the app using react-native run-android the app starts but gives me a redBox screen that shows an error:

Loading dependency graph, done.
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `C:\Users\Alaa\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\myProject\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `C:\Users\Alaa\Documents\ReactNativeProjects\myProject\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

It tells me that the index.js file is not found but it is already there!
Can you help me guys, I've been searching for this problem for about 1 day.
I tried to clean the cache and install the npm again but didn't work.
I tried to change the version too but didn't work.

Comment: it is not an issue with `0.59.1`. If you upgraded from older version of React Native, there some major changes in files and that is why you will get that error. Please see [rn-diff-purge](https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge)

Answer (score 4):

I was also getting the same problem. There is no problem with the react native version. My react native version is 0.59.1. I just solved it by using

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Comment: I tried resetting cache but didn't work with me.
What worked with me is using 0.58.6 version solved my problem

Comment: either that, or this `react-native start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 3):

I guys, but maybe a lot of people do not know the following:

First make sure that device is connected:
adb devices

Open 2 cmd's windows (Windowskey+R [cmd]) and...

1) in First Window : react-native start -- --reset-cache

2) in Second Window : react-native run-android

Answer (score 1):

open terminal and run this code 
'watchman watch-del-all && react-native start -- --reset-cache'

Answer (score 0):

I tried resetting cache and deleting node_modules files but didn't work with me.
What worked with me is using 0.58.6 version when first creating the app (react-native init --version 0.58.6 name) solved my problem.
Thanks, guys!

Comment: You didn't need to. Use latest version and just start the packager manually with `react-native start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally deleted my index.js file. Maybe it helps?

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error. I just downgrade the react-native version to 0.58.6 and it works for me :)

Try to run following command and It might work.

```
> npm i react-native@0.58.6
```

Comment: In newer version of react-native, Metro instance is launched with wrong working directory and no project root is passed in launchPackager.

Answer (score -1):

This is happening for latest version `0.59.1` I guess it is not stable. Stable version is `0.58.6`. Better to create new project with that particular version as `react-native init --version = "0.58.6" <Your App Name>` .

Comment: "I guess it is not stable" ?